# Get Keras LSTM output inside Tensorflow code

Tags: python-3.x, tensorflow, keras, lstm

I'm working with time-variant graph embedding, where at each time step, the adjacency matrix of the graph changes. The main idea is to perform the node embedding of each timestep of the graph by looking to a set of node features and the adjacency matrix. The node embedding step is long and complicated, and is not part of the core of the problem, so I will skip this part. Suffice it to say that I use Graph Convolutional Network to embed the nodes.

Consider that I have a stack of B adjacency matrices A with sizes NxN, where B = batch size and N = number of nodes in the graph. Also, the matrices are stacked according to a time series, where matrix in index i comes before matrix in index i+1. I have already embedded the nodes of the graph, which results in a matrix of dimensions B x N x E, where E = size of the embedding (parameter). Note that the model has to deal with any graph, therefore, N is not a parameter. Another important comment is that each batch contains adjacency matrices from the same graph, and therefore all matrices of a batch have the same number of node, but the matrices of other batches may have different number of nodes.

I now need to pass these embedding through an LSTM cell. I never used Keras before, so I'm having a hard time making the Keras LSTM blend in my Tensorflow code. What I want to do is: pass each node embedding through an LSTM such that the number of timesteps = B and the LSTM batch size = N, that is, the input to my LSTM has the shape [N, B, E], where N and B are only known through execution time. I want the output of my LSTM to have the shape of [B, E*E]. The embedding matrix is called here self.embed_mat. Here is my code:

```py
def _LSTM_layer(self):
    with tf.variable_scope(self.scope, reuse=tf.AUTO_REUSE), tf.device(self.device): 
            in_shape = tf.shape(self.embed_mat)
            lstm_input = tf.reshape(self.embed_mat, [in_shape[1], in_shape[0], EMBED_SIZE]) #lstm = [N, B, E]
            input_plh = K.placeholder(name="lstm_input", shape=(None, None, EMBED_SIZE))
            lstm = LSTM(EMBED_SIZE*EMBED_SIZE, input_shape=(None, None, EMBED_SIZE))
            get_output = K.function(inputs=[input_plh], outputs=[lstm(input_plh)])
            h = get_output([lstm_input])
```

I am a bit lost with the K.function part. All I want is the output tensor of the LSTM cell. I've seen that in order to get that with Keras, we need to use K.function, but I don't quite get it what it does. When I call get_output([lstm_input]), I get the following error:

```
tensorflow.python.framework.errors_impl.InvalidArgumentError: You must feed a value for placeholder tensor 'worker_global/A/shape' with dtype int64 and shape [?]
```

Here, A is the stacked adjacency matrices with dimension BxNxN. What is going on here? Does the value of N needs to be known during graph building step? I think I made some dumb mistake with the LSTM cell, but I can't get what it is.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

If you want to get the output of your LSTM layer "out" given input of "inp" in a keras Sequential() model called "model," where "inp" is your first / input layer and "out" is an LSTM layer that happens to be, for the sake of this example, in the 4th position in your sequential model, you would obtain the output of that LSTM layer from the  data you call "lstm_input" above with the following code:

```
inp = model.layers[0].input

out = model.layers[3].output

inp_to_out = K.function([inp], [out])

output = inp_to_out([lstm_input])
```